# R.attr.cardViewStyle can not be resolved and can not be edditted?

Tags: android, resources, attr, inflate, cardview

I am new devoloper. I am using CardView in my xml. When I open app, I get the below error in my logcat.

" Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView"

After getting this error I have googled but solutions that I have found from internet, didnt solve my problem. My problem is [defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51099742/getting-error-inflating-cardview-despite-of-using-last-version).

When I declare to CardView class I have seen [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YPcD.jpg) cardViewStyle can not be resolved because of that There is no cardViewStyle in R.attr . How can I fix this problem? Pls help me :) thank you

Comment: do you use different versions of support libraries in your project.?

Comment: Can you check my support libraries from " My problem is defined here" ? my gradle is over there. I am using 27 version all of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency in your app level gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: What is the difference between 26.1.0 and 27.1.1 ? I have tried 27.1.0 before, cardviewStyle has been added either. and when I add 26.1.0 it's not accepted because of using 27 libraries.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 27

Comment: then try with 27.1.0 or higher version

Comment: I think this solved my problem. but after that I'm getting an error like this ;

abstract method "void com.squareup.picasso.Callback.onError(java.lang.Exception)

I'm using last version picasso library, I dont understand what it is

Comment: `Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //do smth when picture is loaded successfully

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            //do smth when there is picture loading error
                        }
                    });` try like this

Comment: sir I have get same error when I did this. Do I need to do all classes ?

Comment: if you used picasso in all the classes use the same and try

Comment: same error sir, using Picasso version of     com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'. And Picasso.with(context) is not used in this last version. We can use Picasso.get(); . I have updated as you mentioned but it's not work and same error :(

Comment: `PicassoProvider.get()
        .load(imageUrl)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.image)
        .tag(context)
        .into(imageView, , new Callback() { @Override public void onSuccess() { //do smth when picture is loaded successfully } @Override public void onError() { //do smth when there is picture loading error } }););`

Comment: are you sure about the PicassoProvider.get() ? its not resolved. And need to say that onsucces and  onError method is running same time.

Comment: try this link: https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/SampleContactsAdapter.java

Comment: cannot find symbol method get(). is it about the picasso version?

Comment: add like this in app gradle `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'` and refer above link for how to use picasso line no:61

Comment: try this also, go to: file->invalidate caches and restart

Comment: same error. Sir I was using picasso like this -->  Picasso p = Picasso.get();
                p.load(model.image).tag(this).into(viewHolder.menu_image). Until last 2 days it was working fine. after getting cardview error I have faced with this error. I think we need to use Picasso not PicassoProvider.

Comment: I'll check and let you know

Comment: Thank you very much for patience and interest sir, 
I am grateful to you :)

Comment: Use like this: `Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);` any doubt refer this link also: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I'm already using like this sir, But I got same error. Error :     java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.squareup.picasso.Callback.onError(java.lang.Exception)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..
add below dependency into app level gradle file..
and define version according compile sdk version..

```
    compileSdkVersion 27


    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

card view used to bind other view into this..
also card view most of time used into recyclerview to show a data ..
more information refer this link .,.
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/

Comment: thanks for interest sir but It's not my solution. beacuse my gradle is already like this. I'm already using these codes that you have mentioned .

Comment: you want to pass style into card view then pass style in xml code.

Comment: sir I have mentioned in question "My problem is defined here"

Comment: <com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/backround_main_page"
            android:id="@+id/menu_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

Comment: this code is remove then run app it run successfuly.

Comment: I dont think so sir, because I have been working for 1 month for this project. This problem exist last 2 days I dont know why. Kernburns was working well. And I am using kernburns and cardview other my projects. They are working well either.

Comment: make one seperate demo then test it working without Kernburns